# Invalid Token using expressjs csurf middleware example

Tags: node.js, express, csrf-protection

I've tried using the expressjs csurf example from https://github.com/expressjs/csurf When using the first example in the Readme, (using Ejs template language), the token validation works fine. When I try using the 'Ignoring Routes' example, on the 'GET /form' to 'POST /process' execution(just as I did in the first example), I get 'invalid token' on the 'POST /process'. The token is being passed to the form on the GET. Any ideas?

Is 'app.use(csrfProtection)' not working? (used in the non working example, if I remove the 'use(csrfP..' and use the methodology from the working example to use the csrf module, IE, passing 'csrfProtection' to the 'get' and 'post' methods, the second example works)

**Works:**

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')

// setup route middlewares
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// create express app
var app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// parse cookies
// we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/form', csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  var tkn = req.csrfToken()
  console.log(tkn)
  res.render('index', { csrfToken: tkn })
})

app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

**html/ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/process" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
        Favorite color: <input type="text" name="favoriteColor">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Does not work:**

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')

// setup route middlewares
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// create express app
var app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// parse cookies
// we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection
app.use(cookieParser())

// create api router
var api = createApiRouter()

// mount api before csrf is appended to the app stack
app.use('/api', api)

// now add csrf, after the "/api" was mounted
app.use(csrfProtection)

app.get('/form', function(req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  var tkn = req.csrfToken()
  console.log(tkn)
  res.render('index', { csrfToken: tkn })
})

app.post('/process', parseForm, function(req, res) {
  res.send('csrf was required to get here')
})

function createApiRouter() {
  var router = new express.Router()

  router.post('/getProfile', function(req, res) {
    res.send('no csrf to get here')
  })

  return router
}

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app2 listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you are not passing the `csrfProtection` middleware to the `POST` processing chain. It should be

```
app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
  res.send('csrf was required to get here')
})
```

Comment: In example Two, Does the line 'app.use(csrfProtection)' not override the need for the 'csrfProtection' inclusion in the route handler?